# Elastic IP + EC2 newb: trying to access my server publicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy, amazon-elastic-ip

I have created an elastic ip and associated it to my server. The ip is: 54.201.18.251

If I try and ping this IP I get:

```
PING 54.201.18.251 (54.201.18.251): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

etc

I found in this tutorial: http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal, that I should do this:

```
Once the Elastic IP has been assigned to an instance, you can describe that instance to find the external DNS name (which will include the external Elastic IP address in it):

$ ec2-describe-instances i-07612d6e | egrep ^INSTANCE | cut -f4
ec2-75-101-137-243.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This goes over my head, I have no idea what this means or how I accomplish this through the AWS management console.

Furthermore, in godaddy I have associated a domain with that IP in the DNS Zone file by associating A (Host): @ to point to the ip: is this correct behaviour to?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by following instructions in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465076/how-to-access-ping-a-server-located-on-aws

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you get the request timeout doesn't mean that your instance is not available, because sometimes the icmp echo traffic is blocked.

Try to access the instance via ssh for example, however make sure that your security group associated with that instance allows that.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial isn't going to help you. You are already on the right track.

I suspect the issue is that your security group does not allow ICMP to get to your server. The security group is the definition of what traffic can get to your server. You can define ports, ICMP, and IP address ranges.